# Can the Rx/Tx Packet Buffer size be changed dynamically on a Linux NIC driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

At the moment, the transmit and receive packet size is defined by a macro

```
#define PKT_BUF_SZ          (VLAN_ETH_FRAME_LEN + NET_IP_ALIGN + 4)
```

So PKT_BUF_SZ comes to around 1524 bytes. So the NIC I am having can handle incoming packets from the network which are <= 1524. Anything bigger than that causes the system to crash or worse reboot.  Using Linux kernel 2.6.32 and RHEL 6.0, and a custom FPGA NIC.

Is there a way to change the PKY_BUF_SZ dynamically by getting the size of the incoming packet from the NIC? Will it add to the overhead? Should the hardware drop the packets before it reaches the driver ?

Any help/suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's been a while since I last worked on a NIC driver, but the typical NIC used to have a *fixed* pool of pre-allocated buffers, typically arranged as a ring list.  When there's a packet flood, there's no time to allow dynamic allocation of buffers based on size.  The host CPU is not even involved with packet reception until the frame has been completely stored in RAM.  So it's really a hardware restriction that requires fixed buffer sizes.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Any jumbo packet frame coming through the wire is dropped by the H/W. But if we relax the feature then some packets will sneak through. But will it lead to crashing/reboots if the buffer size is smaller than the incoming packet. As in illegal access to the memory?

Comment: *"But if we relax the feature then..."* -- What silly scenario are you stipulating?  Check the datasheet and/or driver of the Ethernet controller that you're using.  Maybe it supports jumbo frames, typically by using more than one buffer (aka fragmentation).

Comment: My bad, it does support jumbo frames as you have mentioned. If the protocol isn't set to receive a jumbo packet. Does my driver have to drop the packet or do I send it up to the protocol layer and let the protocol handle it? My issue is that system reboots when the NIC receives packets larger than the MTU size, which 1524 bytes. Say, for example, the packet size of 1800 bytes is being received. Is it because my ring buffer gets exhausted?

Once again, thank you for the advice.  There is no facility in the driver code to handle jumbo MTUs. I probably will need to add that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that can be answered without knowledge of the specific controller. They all work differently in details.

Some broadcom NICs for example have different-sized pools of buffers from which the controller will select an appropriate one based on the frame size.  For example, a pool of small (256) byte buffers, a pool of standard size (1536 or so) buffers, and a pool of jumbo buffers.

Some intel NICs have allowed a list of fixed size buffers together with a maximum frame size and it will then pull as many consecutive buffers as needed (not sure linux ever supported this use though -- it's much more complicated for software to handle).

But the most common model that most NICs use (and in fact, I believe all of the commercial ones *can* be used this way): they expect an entire frame to fit in a single buffer, and your single buffer size needs to accommodate the largest frame you will receive.

Given that your NIC is a custom FPGA one, only its designers can advise you on the specifics you're asking. If linux is crashing when larger packets come through, then most likely either your allocated buffer size is not as large as you are telling the NIC it is (leading to overflow), or the NIC has a bug that is causing it to write into some other memory area.

Comment: Cheers Gil, I think you have covered all the possible scenarios. And you might have provided me with the answer I was looking for, in the last paragraph. Have to decide if the NIC is going to support jumbo size buffers and then make the necessary changes in software. Need to get in touch with the H/W engineer and get him to help me out wit this. Also, increase the standard buffer size to 1600 so it accommodates packets around the standard size of 1536 bytes.